# LTE propagation models

Tags: lte, propagation

There's different terminology for propagation models like Urban, Suburban, etc.

I understand it means different configurations for simulations, my doubt is ¿what is the difference between an urban model and a suburban model in easily understood terms?

I mean, urban has more users than suburban? urban has better coverage than suburban? Suburban has less PRB to allocate users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models are generally empirically determined based on real life testing. Urban typically describes an environment where buildings are more plentiful and taller than suburban. Urban would also have less vegetative cover than suburban. This matters because of reflections that occur on objects as the radio wave propagates.